# Errors in my Fraction program (Java)

Tags: java

Hi all I am writing a fraction program in Java. When I run the program I get these following Errors.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArithmeticException
   at PJ1.Fraction.setFraction(Fraction.java:63)
   at PJ1.Fraction.<init>(Fraction.java:55)
   at PJ1.Fraction.add(Fraction.java:89)
   at PJ1.Fraction.main(Fraction.java:238)
```

I'm not sure where/why the error is occurring.

```
    package PJ1;

public class Fraction implements FractionInterface, Comparable<Fraction>
{
   private   int numerator;  
   private   int denominator;  

   public Fraction()
   {
       // set fraction to default = 0/1
       setFraction(0,1);
   }   // end default constructor

   public Fraction(int num, int den)
   {
       // implement this method!
       setFraction(num,den);
   }   // end constructor

   public void setFraction(int num, int den)
   {
       // implement this method!
       // return FractionException if initial Denominator is 0
       if(den==0)
           throw new ArithmeticException();
       if(den<0){
       if(num<0){
           den *=-1;
           num *=-1;
       }
       else{
           den*=-1;
           num*=-1;

       }
       }
   }   // end setFraction

   public double toDouble()
   {
       // return double floating point value
       // implement this method!
       return (double) numerator / denominator;
   }   // end toDouble

   public FractionInterface add(FractionInterface aFraction)
   {
// return a new Fraction object
// a/b + c/d is (ad + cb)/(bd)
// implement this method!
       Fraction z = new Fraction((numerator *((Fraction)aFraction).denominator) +
               (denominator *((Fraction)aFraction).numerator),
               denominator * ((Fraction)aFraction).denominator);
       z.reduceFractionToLowestTerms();
       return z;
   }   // end add

   public FractionInterface subtract(FractionInterface aFraction)
   {
// return a new Fraction object
// a/b - c/d is (ad - cb)/(bd)
// implement this method!
       Fraction z = new Fraction((numerator *((Fraction)aFraction).denominator) -
               (denominator *((Fraction)aFraction).numerator),
               denominator * ((Fraction)aFraction).denominator);
       z.reduceFractionToLowestTerms();
       return z;
   }   // end subtract

   public FractionInterface multiply(FractionInterface aFraction)
   {
// return a new Fraction object
// a/b * c/d is (ac)/(bd)
// implement this method!
       Fraction z = new Fraction((numerator *((Fraction)aFraction).denominator) *
               (denominator *((Fraction)aFraction).numerator),
               denominator * ((Fraction)aFraction).denominator);
       z.reduceFractionToLowestTerms();
       return z;

   }   // end multiply

   public FractionInterface divide(FractionInterface aFraction)
   {
// return a new Fraction object
// return FractionException if aFraction is 0
// a/b / c/d is (ad)/(bc)
// implement this method!
       Fraction z = new Fraction((numerator *((Fraction)aFraction).denominator) /
               (denominator *((Fraction)aFraction).numerator),
               denominator * ((Fraction)aFraction).denominator);
       z.reduceFractionToLowestTerms();
       return z;
       }   // end divide

   public FractionInterface getReciprocal()
   {
// return a new Fraction object
// return FractionException if new Fraction is 0
// implement this method!
       if(numerator ==0)
           throw new ArithmeticException();
       return new Fraction(denominator, numerator);

   } // end getReciprocal


   public boolean equals(Object other)
   {
// implement this method!
       ((Fraction)other).reduceFractionToLowestTerms();
       return (numerator == ((Fraction)other).numerator) && (denominator == ((Fraction)other).denominator);

   } // end equals


   public int compareTo(Fraction other)
   {
// implement this method!
       if(toDouble() > other.toDouble()){
           return 2;
       }
       else if(toDouble() < other.toDouble()){
           return -2;
           }
       else{
           return 0;
       } }
       // end compareTo


   public String toString()
   {
       return numerator + "/" + denominator;
   } // end toString
```

**Listed below are the other codes that I am not supposed to modify.**

```
private void reduceFractionToLowestTerms()
   {
// implement this method!
//
// Outline:
// compute GCD of numerator & denominator
// GCD works for + numeratorbers.
// So, you should eliminate - sign
// then reduce numeratorbers : numerator/GCD and denominator/GCD
       boolean neg = false;
       if(numerator== -1){
           numerator *= -1;
           neg = true;
       }
       int gcd = GCD(Math.abs(numerator), Math.abs(denominator));

       numerator = numerator / gcd;
       denominator = denominator / gcd;
       if(neg==true){
           numerator *=-1;
       }
   }   // end reduceFractionToLowestTerms

   /** Task: Computes the greatest common divisor of two integers.
   * @param integerOne   an integer
   * @param integerTwo   another integer
   * @return the greatest common divisor of the two integers */
   private int GCD(int integerOne, int integerTwo)
   {
       int result;

       if (integerOne % integerTwo == 0)
           result = integerTwo;
       else
           result = GCD(integerTwo, integerOne % integerTwo);

       return result;
   }   // end GCD


   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   // Simple test is provided here

   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
       FractionInterface firstOperand = null;
       FractionInterface secondOperand = null;
       FractionInterface result = null;
double doubleResult = 0.0;

       Fraction nineSixteenths = new Fraction(9, 16);   // 9/16
       Fraction oneFourth = new Fraction(1, 4); // 1/4

       System.out.println("\n=========================================\n");
       // 7/8 + 9/16
       firstOperand = new Fraction(7, 8);
       result = firstOperand.add(nineSixteenths);
       System.out.println("The sum of " + firstOperand + " and " +
               nineSixteenths + " is \t\t" + result);
       System.out.println("\tExpected result :\t\t23/16\n");

       // 9/16 - 7/8
       firstOperand = nineSixteenths;
       secondOperand = new Fraction(7, 8);
       result = firstOperand.subtract(secondOperand);
       System.out.println("The difference of " + firstOperand   +
               " and " +   secondOperand + " is \t" + result);
       System.out.println("\tExpected result :\t\t-5/16\n");


       // 15/-2 * 1/4
       firstOperand = new Fraction(15, -2);
       result = firstOperand.multiply(oneFourth);
       System.out.println("The product of " + firstOperand   +
               " and " +   oneFourth + " is \t" + result);
       System.out.println("\tExpected result :\t\t-15/8\n");

       // (-21/2) / (3/7)
       firstOperand = new Fraction(-21, 2);
       secondOperand= new Fraction(3, 7);
       result = firstOperand.divide(secondOperand);
       System.out.println("The quotient of " + firstOperand   +
               " and " +   secondOperand + " is \t" + result);
       System.out.println("\tExpected result :\t\t-49/2\n");

       // -21/2 + 7/8
       firstOperand = new Fraction(-21, 2);
       secondOperand= new Fraction(7, 8);
       result = firstOperand.add(secondOperand);
       System.out.println("The sum of " + firstOperand   +
               " and " +   secondOperand + " is \t\t" + result);
       System.out.println("\tExpected result :\t\t-77/8\n");


// 0/10, 5/(-15), (-22)/7
       firstOperand = new Fraction(0, 10);
doubleResult = firstOperand.toDouble();
       System.out.println("The double floating point value of " + firstOperand   + " is \t" + doubleResult);
       System.out.println("\tExpected result \t\t\t0.0\n");
       firstOperand = new Fraction(1, -3);
doubleResult = firstOperand.toDouble();
       System.out.println("The double floating point value of " + firstOperand   + " is \t" + doubleResult);
       System.out.println("\tExpected result \t\t\t-0.333333333...\n");
       firstOperand = new Fraction(-22, 7);
doubleResult = firstOperand.toDouble();
       System.out.println("The double floating point value of " + firstOperand   + " is \t" + doubleResult);
       System.out.println("\tExpected result \t\t\t-3.142857142857143");
       System.out.println("\n=========================================\n");
       firstOperand = new Fraction(-21, 2);
       System.out.println("First = " + firstOperand);
       // equality check
       System.out.println("check First equals First: ");
       if (firstOperand.equals(firstOperand))
           System.out.println("Identity of fractions OK");
       else
           System.out.println("ERROR in identity of fractions");

       secondOperand = new Fraction(-42, 4);
       System.out.println("\nSecond = " + secondOperand);
       System.out.println("check First equals Second: ");
       if (firstOperand.equals(secondOperand))
           System.out.println("Equality of fractions OK");
       else
           System.out.println("ERROR in equality of fractions");

       // comparison check
       Fraction first = (Fraction)firstOperand;
       Fraction second = (Fraction)secondOperand;

       System.out.println("\ncheck First compareTo Second: ");
       if (first.compareTo(second) == 0)
           System.out.println("Fractions == operator OK");
       else
           System.out.println("ERROR in fractions == operator");

       second = new Fraction(7, 8);
       System.out.println("\nSecond = " + second);
       System.out.println("check First compareTo Second: ");
       if (first.compareTo(second) < 0)
           System.out.println("Fractions < operator OK");
       else
           System.out.println("ERROR in fractions < operator");

       System.out.println("\ncheck Second compareTo First: ");
       if (second.compareTo(first) > 0)
           System.out.println("Fractions > operator OK");
       else
           System.out.println("ERROR in fractions > operator");

       System.out.println("\n=========================================");

       System.out.println("\ncheck FractionException: 1/0");
       try {
           Fraction a1 = new Fraction(1, 0);      
       System.out.println("Error! No FractionException");
       }
       catch ( FractionException fe )
    {
       System.err.printf( "Exception: %s\n", fe );
    } // end catch
       System.out.println("Expected result : FractionException!\n");

       System.out.println("\ncheck FractionException: division");
       try {
           Fraction a2 = new Fraction();      
           Fraction a3 = new Fraction(1, 2);      
           a3.divide(a2);
       System.out.println("Error! No FractionException");
       }
       catch ( FractionException fe )
    {
       System.err.printf( "Exception: %s\n", fe );
    } // end catch
       System.out.println("Expected result : FractionException!\n");

   }   // end main
} // end Fraction

These are the following parts that I am given but I am not supposed to Modify.

/************************************************************************************
* Do not modify this file.
* FractionException class. It is used by Fraction class
*************************************************************************************/

    package PJ1;

    public class FractionException extends RuntimeException
    {
    public FractionException()
    {
       this("");
    }

    public FractionException(String errorMsg)
    {
       super(errorMsg);
    }

    }

* This file specifies methods for FractionInterface       */
/* Do not modify this file!!             */

package PJ1;

public interface FractionInterface
{
/** Task: Sets a fraction to a given value.
* @param num is the integer numerator
* @param den is the integer denominator
* @throws ArithmeticException if denominator is 0 */
public void setFraction(int num, int den);

   /** Task: convert a fraction to double value
   * @return the double floating point value of a fraction */
   public double toDouble();


   /** Task: Adds two fractions.
   * @param aFraction is a fraction that is the second operand of the addition
   * @return a fraction which is the sum of the invoking fraction and the aFraction */
   public FractionInterface add(FractionInterface aFraction);



   /** Task: Subtracts two fractions.
   * @param aFraction a fraction that is the second operand of the subtraction
   * @return a fraction which is the difference of the invoking fraction and the second operand */
   public FractionInterface subtract(FractionInterface aFraction);

   /** Task: Multiplies two fractions.
   * @param aFraction a fraction that is the second operand of the multiplication
   * @return a fraction which is the product of the invoking fraction and the aFraction*/
   public FractionInterface multiply(FractionInterface aFraction);

   /** Task: Divides two fractions.
   * @param aFraction a fraction that is the second operand of the division
   * @return a fraction which the quotient of the invoking fraction and the aFraction
* @throws FractionException if aFraction is 0 */
   public FractionInterface divide(FractionInterface aFraction);

   /** Task: Get's the fraction's reciprocal
   * @return the reciprocal of the invoking fraction
* @throws FractionException if the new number with denominator is 0*/
   public FractionInterface getReciprocal();

}
```

Comment: Please can you indicate line 63 in your code? (Although I strongly suspect it's the one where you write `throw new ArithmeticException();`)

Comment: The `throw new ArithmeticException();` doesn't match with the comment immediately above it, which says `FractionException`.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm not sure where/why the error is occurring.

As your stack trace tells it,
the exception is thrown on line 63 in `Fraction.java`,
this must be it:

> ```
>    if(den==0)
>        throw new ArithmeticException();
> ```

Don't call this function with 0 as denominator.

Comment: Sorry I'm a bit confused. I'm supposed to throw a exception if the denominator is equal to 0 since you can't divide by 0. Am I using the wrong kind of exception?

Comment: No, it's not the "wrong" type of exception, but your question seems to by "why is this type of exception being thrown, and from where" when the line of code you have indicated contains a throw statement of that exact exception type. It's unclear what you're actually asking...

Comment: I see what you're saying. However even if I remove
if(den==0)
       throw new ArithmeticException();

i still get the same error.

Comment: The problem is NOT that you're throwing an exception. That's a good thing. That's designed to protect you. The problem is that you're calling `setFraction(..., 0)`, with 0 as the second parameter, the denominator. A fraction with 0 denominator doesn't make much sense does it? That's what the exception is there, to validate the input, and signal to you invalid input. Check where you call `setFraction` with a 0 as the denominator. That's what you need to fix.